# How do I auto generate .ts files in VSCode?

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a .json file that changes quite often and I would like to auto generate a .ts file every time the .json file is saved.

I want to write the logic of the converter from the .json to .ts myself.
How is this achieved with VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, this may not be the best approach, but there is a plugin called [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) that executes a command when you save a file. If you have a script in ts/js that converts the .json to .ts, you can execute it with the nodejs runtime.

A sample config could look like:

```json
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": "file.json$",
            "cmd": "ts-node export.ts ${file}"
        },
    ]
}
```

Your `export.ts` script would be running in the nodejs runtime, so you'll have access to the [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). This gives you the ability to read and write files to the disk. A sample could look like:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(process.argv[2], function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  
  //conversion would be here
  let jsonPayload = data;

  fs.appendFile('newTsFile.ts', jsonPayload, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Updated!');
  }); 
});
```

Comment: That exactly what I need. How do you get it to match *.json files in a specific folder? Tried everything, eg.  match: "*\\translations\\.json$"

Comment: It's a regex, so try something like `translations\/.*\.json`

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Looks like I forgot to double escape the slashes: `translations\\/.*\\.json`. See the instructions for the config here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave

Comment: This is what worked for me: `.translations.json$`. It's not documented in very clear terms.